# R Highcharter - firePointEvent When Action Button is Clicked

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, treemap, r-highcharter

I am using R, Shiny, and Highcharter and I would like to click an Action Button and have the treemap drill down into a section that I designate. So for instance I click the "mybutton" action button and it drills down into the Europe section. I am able to capture the click event if the user actually clicks on the TreeMap. But I would like to reverse the process to click on an Action Button and have the TreeMap zoom into a section of the TreeMap that I manually designate. Reproducible code:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")
library("shinyjs")
library("treemap")
library("viridisLite")
data(GNI2014)

jscode <- "shinyjs.drillDownFunction = function() {
  var chart = $('#hcontainer').highcharts();
  chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click');
  console.log(chart);}"

jscode2 <- "shinyjs.drillDownFunction2 = function() {
  var chart = $('#hcontainer').highcharts();
  chart.series[0].data[0].series.hcEvents.click[0]();
  console.log(chart);}"

jscode3 <- "shinyjs.drillDownFunction3 = function() {
  var chart = $('#hcontainer').highcharts();
  Highcharts.fireEvent(chart.series[0].data[0], 'click');
  console.log(chart);}"

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = "drillDownFunction"),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode2, functions = "drillDownFunction2"),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode3, functions = "drillDownFunction3"),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4, actionButton("mybutton", "Drill Down into TreeMap"),
                        actionButton("mybutton2", "Drill Down into TreeMap"),
                        actionButton("mybutton3", "Drill Down into TreeMap")))
    )

server <- function(input, output) {      

  tm <- treemap(GNI2014, index = c("continent", "iso3"),
                vSize = "GNI", vColor = "population",
                type = "value", palette = magma(12))

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    hctreemap(tm, allowDrillToNode = TRUE, allowPointSelect = TRUE) %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Gross National Income World Data")
  })

  shinyjs::onclick("mybutton", {
    js$drillDownFunction()
  })

  shinyjs::onclick("mybutton2", {
    js$drillDownFunction2()
  })

  shinyjs::onclick("mybutton3", {
    js$drillDownFunction3()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you try to make drilldown on button click in pure javascript? You would want to use drillToNode method. Here you have example of how to do this in JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ljoqbc0h/

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you. Only issue is when I drilldown the 'Back' button no longer displays to allow the user to drill back up. In the jsfiddle you provided it seems that button remained.

Comment: You're welcome. I can take a look at 'Back' button and dig into it but I am not good with R and you would have to send me a new code with implemented drillToNode method. Another thing I can suggest is: if something works with JS on jsFiddle but not with R, you can contact author of Highcharter wrapper or you can look for help on R community forum.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a **drillToNode** method. Here you have an example of how to do this in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ljoqbc0h

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  chart.series[0].drillToNode('id_0');
})
```